# Game idea "square or not"

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, quadrilateral

I have an idea of a quadrilateral / square  game, and am looking for help.

For the moment lets call it the "Square or Not " game.

Imagine we have a big stack of cards with on each
card some property of a square.

The properties have the following limitations:

- The property is valid for square.
- The property is valid for some quadrilateral that is not a square (so the property doesn't define the quadrilateral as a square)
- The property is expressable in a short sentence, and understandable for a twelf year old.(except maybe some geometrical terms, that can be explained in a booklet)

Examples of valid properties:

- the quadrilateral is a rectangle.
- the quadrilateral has a line of symmetry.
- a diagonal cuts the quadrilateral in two similar triangles.
- a bimedian cuts the quadrilateral in half (by area).
- the quadrilateral has at least one right angle.
- two adjecent sides have the same length.
- the two diagonals have the same length.
- the quadrilateral is convex.

Examples of invalid properties:

- a diagonal lies outside the quadrilateral (not valid for a square).
- the area of the circumscribed circle is twice the area of the inscribed circle (this implies the quadrilateral is a square).

the game (solitaire version)

The player picks at random a dozen property cards and must decide if a 
quadrilateral with all these properties is nescesarily a square or not.

If it is a square: (Probably it is) - what is the minimal number of properties that needs to be removed so that the quadrilateral is not necesary a square?

What help I need:

- more properties of a square, (will later add my own list of properties)
- who could help me making this game (or a software version of it)

Comment: I don't this kind of "discussion" question is a good fit for Math.SE -- maybe alt.math.recreational would be a better forum.  In any case "diagonals bisect one another" is my contribution.